# How to import a Pod from a development pod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, podfile

I'm creating a react-native module I would like for this custom module to import another pod, specifically AFNetworking.

How do I go about this?

What I've done:

- Adding   `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'` to my project's Podfile
- Added   `s.dependency "AFNetworking"` in my custom module's podspec
- `import "AFNetworking.h"` in `MyModule.mm`

I get the error `Expected unqualified-id`

I've tried all variations of

```
#import “../../../Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h”
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

None of which seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

See [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)